# How to remove &amp when Convert to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

In my ASP.NET web, i have a convert to Excel function, iam using CarlosAG.convert. My problem is When some table field in database contain value "&" (format field = text, ex: "you & i"), it change to &amp in excel ex: you "&amp"; i.
Please help me solve this.

code to write in excel (CarlosAG):

```
WorksheetRow wr = new WorksheetRow();
DataTable dt = Testing;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
wr.Cells.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["TestingName"]), DataType.String, "s140");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is HtmlDecode the string, that will remove any special encoding you used.  So the following code should do the trick.

```
WorksheetRow wr = new WorksheetRow();
DataTable dt = Testing;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
wr.Cells.Add(Server.HtmlDecode(Convert.ToString(dr["TestingName"])), DataType.String, "s140");
}
```